# 2006 Buick Rendezvous 3.5 will not rev over 3500 rpm in park or driving with pedal to the metal. Any ideas?

Tags: engine, electrical, buick, rendezvous

3.5 will not rev over 3500 rpm. PO 449 is the only code stored. It will not rev over 3500 cold or hot.          After driving   10-15  minutes seems like the transmission is searching for a gear, just what it acts like. Then top speed is on 10 mph for a bit then picks back up but still will not rev over 3500 rpm still bucking.  I do know that it's not the catalytic converter.  Any more ideas.

Comment: PO 449 is the only code stored.

Comment: Have you checked your transmission fluid level?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does it do the same when it's cold? P0449 has to do with EVAP system, but that shouldn't cause it not to rev out correctly.

Comment: I have checked transmission fluid. It's good.  Yes does the same cold or operating temperature, but it does get worse the longer you drive it.

Comment: Check the other modules for codes. Check exhaust back-pressure possibly. Any other lights or symptoms?

Comment: No other lights or symptoms. How can I check exhaust back pressure?  Wouldn't codes for other modules show on the scan

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that is probably a computer controlled throttle. If the engine detects a significant problem, it could be in "limp" mode, cutting power so you don't harm the engine.

Comment: Chris how do I detect limp mode?

Comment: In almost any case the engine light would come on if this were the case

Answer (score 0):

P0449 is EVAP system related - it's quite common on those for the EVAP vent canister solenoid to fail so that would be my prime suspect. Especially if you are experiencing any roughness at idle or if the car seems to be struggling to start.

The limited revs/acceleration sounds very much like the error code has tripped the engine into limp mode but I can't be certain.

If the problem is the vent solenoid the good news is that it's not a particularly expensive part (it's ~ $120), the bad news is that it's located on top of the fuel tank so it's a tank-out job to swap it. Not the easiest one to do at home!